Multiplication of binomial coefficients
So is there any way to derive the multiplication of binomial coefficients?
straight up opening it results in $\frac{(n!)^{n+1}}{[n(n-1)^2(n-2)^3...3^{n-2}2^{n-1}1^n]^2} $
(square on bottom full bracket due it being 2 series)
But this doesnt seem to satisfy the example i put into it ($n=5,4$) what could be going wrong and is there any  alternative way to find the multiplication of binomial coefficients. (corrections are always welcome,appreciated (im just a highschooler so might be wrong)).
Edit:-1  I found the error in the formula the $(n!)^n$ is $(n!)^n+1$ because opening the binomial coefficients always gives $n+1$ terms. The formula is still too lengthy to practically use without a calculator so the question for a simpler/straightforward version still remains

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Noted! Will try to from next time.. (i try to but i always fail to understand it.)

@Scypher_Tzu I tried to put in the MathJax, I would recommend checking that I haven't unintentionally changed the meaning of what you were trying to portray.

yes that is correct thank you!

The edit is still not "put in MathJax". It seems that saying "i try to" is not really true.

My apologies sir!, trying to use the mathrm command is not working. You are free to suggest an edit i will gladly add it.

Starting from @Gwen good answer
$$P_n=\frac{(n!)^{n+1}}{[0!1!2!...n!]^2}=\frac{(n!)^{n+1}}{\big(G(n+2)\big)^2}$$ where appears the Barnes G function.
Using Stirling approximation
$$\log(P_n)=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2} n \log \left(\frac{e^2}{2 \pi    n}\right)+\log \left(\frac{A^2}{\sqrt[12]{e} \sqrt{2 \pi }
   \sqrt[3]{n}}\right)-\frac{1}{12 n}+\frac{1}{180 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
For $P_n$ the relative error is smaller than $0.001$% as soon as $n>6$.
For $n=20$ the above formula gives $\color{red}{170.156413}49$.

i was wondering if you could clarify what the A^2 in the bracket is and what the O(n^-3) is? other than that it all seems correct.

@Scypher_Tzu. Sorry ! $A$ is Glaisher constant and the big $O$ notation. If you wish more terms, just ask. Cheers :-)

Product of all binomial coefficients is essentially
$\frac{(n!)^{n+1}}{\big[n!(n-1)!(n-2)!...(n-n+1)!(n-n)!\big]×\big[0!1!2!3!4!...(n-1)!n!\big]}$
$$=\frac{(n!)^{n+1}}{[0!1!2!...n!]^2}$$
$$=\frac{(n!)^{n+1}}{[1^{n}2^{n-1}3^{n-2}...(n-1)^2n]^2}$$
$$=\frac{1^{n+1}2^{n+1}...{n}^{n+1}}{[1^{2n}2^{2n-2}3^{2n-4}...(n-1)^4n^2]}$$
$$=1^{1-n}×2^{3-n}×3^{5-n}×...(n-1)^{n-3}×n^{n-1}$$
$$=\prod_{k=1}^n \bigg(\frac{n-k+1}{k}\bigg)^{n-2k+1},n-2k+1≥0$$
